# Oracle DB: Created Tablespace doesn't appear under DBA_TS_Quotas

Tags: oracle

In my homework assignment, I am asked to create a tablespace called TOOLS. So I used the following command:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE TOOLS
DATAFILE 'tools1_data.dbf'
SIZE 10M;
```

So I got an output that `"Tablespace created"`

I have been asked to assign an existing user to this table space and I did that successfully without any issue. However, when I query the dba_ts_quotas, I am not able to see this tablespace in that list:

[image]

What could I be doing wrong here? Any insight is greatly appreciated here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only find tablespace information in `dba_ts_quotas` when you grant quota on it to an specific user.

*Quota is the amount of space a specific user can use in a determined tablespace.*

> DBA_TS_QUOTAS describes tablespace quotas for all users.

So you have to issue a

```
ALTER USER xxxx QUOTA yyy ON tablespacename ;
```

Where

- `xxxx` is the user who you are granting quota on the specific tablespace
- `yyyy` is the quota. It can be an integer with K as Kilobytes, M as Megabytes or G as gigabytes. If you don't want to limit the quota, you use then `quota unlimited`
- `tablespacename` is the tablespace you have created.

Example

```
ALTER USER SCOTT QUOTA UNLIMITED ON TOOLS;
```

Demo

```
SQL> create tablespace tbdemo datafile '/bbdd_odcgrc1r/datos/tbdemo.dbf' size 10M autoextend on next 10m maxsize 10g ;

Tablespace created.

SQL> alter user test1 quota unlimited on tbdemo ;

User altered.

SQL> desc dba_ts_quotas
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 TABLESPACE_NAME                           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 USERNAME                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
 BYTES                                              NUMBER
 MAX_BYTES                                          NUMBER
 BLOCKS                                             NUMBER
 MAX_BLOCKS                                         NUMBER
 DROPPED                                            VARCHAR2(3)

SQL> select tablespace_name,username,max_bytes from dba_ts_quotas
  2  where tablespace_name = 'TBDEMO' ;

TABLESPACE    USERNAME       MAX_BYTES
--------------------------------------
TBDEMO        TEST1          -1
```

`-1` indicates unlimited quota on this tablespace for the user `TEST1`

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: you're welcome @CrazyCoder